# I have this dataset on foged signature verification and I have no idea how to load the dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, load

The dataset I have is a bit different and i tried out a few methods. I got the dataset from this [website](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/mariomu/research.html) . I desperately need to load the data but I can't. Can anyone help me out with the loading the dataset? I have attached the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3P1E.png) of the dataset I downloaded.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Re-edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('yourfilename.csv')
```

Comment: Please spend time explaining, how and why your solution answers the question.

Comment: I wasn't expecting this but your solution co-incidentally worked. At least i could load the data, now i dont really know how i can use it. Thanks anway :D